# connect to mysql with wavemaker

Tags: mysql, wavemaker

I have recently downloaded Wavemaker because I feel it best suites my needs, however when I try and connect to my database on a mysql server hosted with godaddy, I keep getting access denied. However I can connect using exactly the same loggin info for sql workbench and razorsql just to see if I had my credentials correct and I have no problem connecting using those other two tools, is it me or is wavemaker being a pain?

Answer (score 2):

Did you remember to install the **MySQL JDBC DRIVER**?

If not you can get it from the MySQL site, or install it on your Linux machine using the appropriate install commands. I had the same problem and after installing the driver everything worked great.

I'm posting my **WaveMaker MySQL connection info** (the database properties file) in hopes it might help:

```
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.connectionUrl=jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/mafiamgr_warmturkey?useUnicode\=yes&characterEncoding\=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior\=convertToNull
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.tableFilter=.*
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.username=topsecret_xref
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.password=568626f144a0c56862568626f14047568626f1412a43
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.reverseNamingStrategy=com.wavemaker.tools.data.reveng.DefaultRevengNamingStrategy
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.schemaFilter=.*
mafiamgr_warmturkeyDB.dialect=com.wavemaker.runtime.data.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: the driverClassName it's a good tips because in the default conecction of wm6.7 it's not by default :)